# How do I apply script before rendering After Effects

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I have this piece of code that uses aerender:

```
const aerender = spawn('C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects 2020\\Support Files\\aerender.exe', 
['-comp', 'main','-project', path +'templates\\1\\template.aep','-output', (path+'results\\'+ customTime +'_'+name +'.mov'),'-RStemplate', renderTemplate,'-s', '1','-e', duration *30      ])
```

The thing is, I have also a script which I can run in AE, which set startTime and endPoint to some layers, I want to run this script from code, before rendering, without opening AE.

I tried awaiting this:

```
const afterfx = spawn('C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects 2020\\Support Files\\AfterFX.exe',
 ['-r', 'C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects 2020\\Support Files\\Scripts\\Startup\\adjust.jsx'        ])
```

I also tried inserting the script in the startup folder, works when opening the project manually, not by the code call.

Comment: Does the adjust script save the AE project file?

Comment: @stib it does not, although if I open AE manually, run the script, export the sequence, I don't care about the changes to the project, but I will give it a go, thanks

Comment: If it doesn't save the project then when you run aerender it will render the project that's saved, meaning it won't show any of the changes.